# enlighten me about UseEffect Loop when data not changing

Tags: reactjs, firebase, use-effect

Hello i have this component and after some reading i have undestand that the useEffect is called again when data in array change but in my case that's not change and i get into a loop.

```
export default function Test() {
  
  const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);
  let values = [];
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllFilledJournauxDates().then(function(response) {
      values = response;
      setDates(values);
    }
    );
  }
  , [dates]);
    
  console.log(values);
  


  return(
    <div>
      {dates.map(date => {
        return <div>{date}</div>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[EDIT 2] adding the funtion getAllFilledJournauxDates()

```
export async function getAllFilledJournauxDates() {
    
        let dates = [];
        let journaux = getAllJournaux()
            .then(response => {
                Object.keys(response).forEach(element => {
                    dates.push(new Date(new Date(response[element].date)).getFullYear() + "-" + (new Date(response[element].date)).getMonth() + "-" + (new Date(response[element].date)).getDate());
                })
            })
        return dates;
}
```

[EDIT]

```
export default function Test() {
  
  const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);
  let values = [];
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect"); // displayed two time in console
    getAllFilledJournauxDates().then(function(response) {
      values = response;
      setDates(values);
      console.log(values); //display the array of dates
    }
    );
  }
  , []);
    
  console.log(values); // display an empty array
  


  return(
    <div>
      {dates.map(date => {
        return <div>{date}</div> // display nothing on screen
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Like suggered by @rowinbot i have removed the variable in array , but nothing yet on the screen, i can see that the variable is filled in my console, and the useEffect look like he is called two times ...
i want to add that at first i try to fill a calendar with  those values but without get the result i wanted i haved render the result most simply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You should remove `dates` from the effect's dependency array.

Effects (a.k.a the functions we pass to the `useEffect` hook) on React runs after rendering, the dependency array acts as a escape hatch for running the effect in case you want to run the Effect **only** after certain dependencies were updated in a given render.

Here you're saying that whenever `dates` updates (its value changes) you want to run the Effect which in turn calls `setDates(...)` and mutates `dates` value, this produces a render of the component and since `dates` changed, the Effect is run once more, and... That happens indefinitely.

Just remove `dates` from the dependency array and you should be fine:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllFilledJournauxDates().then(function(response) {
      values = response;
      setDates(values);
    }
    );
  }
  , []);
```

Just remember to keep the dependency array even if its empty, this basically tells React to only run your effect "once" (React 18' strict mode makes this a bit different on development) and prevents the loop.

Avoiding the depedency array entirely (omitting it) would result in the same outcome, an infinite loop, this tells React that on **every** render, you want to run the effect, which causes another render... And cycles *eternally*.

You can read more about Effects in the [beta React docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects) which does a great job summarizing its semantics.

Comment: thank you for your answer , after testing sorry but i come with more question , i update my post to show you

Comment: done but nothing appear on the screen yet

Comment: @AWEMAAgenceWebMarketing `values` is defined *during* renders, effects runs *after* renders, so if for a given render you actually fetch, by the time the console.log gets called the render will not be run, it effectively runs after executing the component's function and "painting" to the screen. You should be logging `dates` instead which value preserves through renders

Comment: @AWEMAAgenceWebMarketing I would put a `console.log` on the promise's then function to see what's the output of `response`

Comment: inside the promise's then function the log give the good result but nothing into the render yet

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code, checkout [this codepen with your exact code](https://codepen.io/rowinbot/pen/eYMYvOx).

Comment: You might be experiencing issues unrelated to that code, maybe because of the `getAllFilledJournauxDates` function. @AWEMAAgenceWebMarketing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245987/discussion-between-awema-agence-web-marketing-and-rowinbot).

Answer (score 0):

You are updating dates inside the useEffect, and that is way on every useEffect rerun you change the dates and that causes it to rerun again and creates a loop. Try to put something else to trigger the useEffect instead of the dates. Maybe you can try to put it on change of "values" instead of dates and fetch response outside of useEffect and put it in values.

```
useEffect(() => {
      setDates(values);
  }
  , [values]);
    
  console.log(values);
```

Comment: This will also cause a re-render, values *identity* is unstable (its being re-created on every render) resulting in the same endless loop

Comment: if he is setting values in some custom functions that fetcehs response only when it needs to and then updates the dates as well it will not cause the loop, if that was the idea

Comment: @NikolaArtukov please can you more explain it's difficult for to catch your purpose , thanks

Comment: if he is changing some data here that can cause to get different "response" after the change for example, he should on that change of data call the new function to get "response", and in that function update the values that will update the dates, if the response is not changing the above solution should work just fine with empty dependancy array. Im not sure what else funcionallity will be in this component and will he have to fetch new data on some changes, in that case he can either put values in dependancy array or just on refetch to update setDates() and not use useEffect at all.

Comment: please give me some code to illustrate , cause with translation in my language i didnt understand yet , sorry for my sad language level